# Problemas com php mailer

Tags: php

É a minha primeira vez a usar o php emailer e obtenho o erro: 
**The following From address failed: tiagotestes@gmail.com**

Esta ai o meu codigo desde já obrigado.

```
    // recebe as Variaveis
    $nome     = $_POST["nome"];
    $email    = $_POST["email"];
    $mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];

    // Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
    include("class.phpmailer.php");

    // Inicia a classe PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com";     // Endereço do servidor SMTP


    // Define o remetente.
    $mail->From     = "tiagotestes@gmail.com"; // Seu e-mail
    $mail->FromName = "thH";       // Seu nome

    // Define os destinatário(s)
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $nome);
    $mail->AddCC('tiago_coelho_1996@hotmail.com', 'Eu'); // Copia
    //$mail->AddBCC('fulano@dominio.com.br', 'Fulano da Silva'); // Cópia Oculta

    // Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML

    // Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
    $mail->Subject = "Mensagem do site"; // Assunto da mensagem
    $mail->Body    = $mensagem;

    // Envia o e-mail
    $enviado = $mail->Send();

    // Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
    if ($enviado) {
       echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";   
    } else {
       echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail !";
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa definir as seguintes propiedades:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'emailusado@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'senhadoemail';
```

O phpmailer funciona como um client que se logará em uma conta do host (no caso gmail) e automaticamente criará e enviará a mensagem.

Nesse caso é necessário que você crie uma conta no gmail pra sua aplicação.

Lembre-se de passar nessa página e habilitar o acesso de aplicações menos seguras: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps Senão o google bloqueia as requisições do seu client

Comment: Muito obrigado a unica mudança que eu tive que fazer foi no ssl para tsl

Comment: Se a resposta nao contemplou a sua duvida, não a marque como solução do problema

Answer (score 0):

Tente acrescentar esta linha:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true
```